# Вопрос про потоки Android java

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

У меня есть поток, который каждые 10 секунд отправляет запрос на сервер и обновляет интерфейс исходят из ответа, так вот умные дядьки рекомендуют в `onPause()` у активити останавливать поток чтобы избежать утечки памяти, но мне нужно чтобы при сворачивании приложения поток оставался активным и уведомлял пользователя об изменениях, а останавливался только в `onDestroy()` как это реализовать?

Comment: При сворачивании вызывается onStop() у активности после onPause(). Даже если в onPause он у тебя будет работать, в onStop он все равно прекратится. Для такой работы существуeт Service.

Comment: Согласен с рекомендацией выше - для таких целей нужно использовать Сервис. А еще, чтоб не делать запросы каждые 10 секунд - лучше держать Сокет соединение.